# Android EditText has fixed input

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext

This part of my program is supposed to be a user input field for the quantity of an item to purchase. What I'm unable to do is to make it so when the program finally runs on the emulator and I change the textfield number in the EditText, named "etxtQuantity" in my case, the number I use is ignored and it reverts to using the default entry. Also my if statement isn't working like I expect either, it accepts everything.

```
private void setupAddRecordButton() {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddCart);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        final TextView countText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAddCartCount);
        EditText quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtQuantity);
        String quantity2 = quantity.getText().toString();
        final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuantityCheck); 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (! quantity2.equals(".") || quantity2.equals("") || quantity2.equals("-")) {
                count++;
                long newId = myDb.insertRow("GTX 950", 140, quantity2);
                myDb.getRow(newId);
                countText.setText("Successfully added " + count + " Times");
            }
            else
            {
                text2.setText("Quantity needed!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: please move the editext code    String quantity2 = quantity.getText().toString(); inside the onclick

Comment: Wow, so fast, it fixed that part of the issue!

Comment: One more thing, my if statement accepts nulls " ", when I thought it would prompt for the else because of my condition?

Comment: you have wrong condition you forget to write ! in every quantitty condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please move the this line
   `String quantity2 = quantity.getText().toString();`

inside the `onClick()`

Comment: You solved the main part of my question so I'll mark you as the answer. I found out my syntax issue on my if statement by changing it to ( ! (quantity2.equals(".") || quantity2.equals("") || quantity2.equals("-")) )

Comment: yes i noticed that too but while i skipped it as i thought u needed the condition that way

Answer (score 1):

initailize your edit text in **onCreate()** callback function of your activity and use **String quantity2 = quantity.getText().toString();** in **onClick()** function of your button

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtQuantity);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddCart);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuantityCheck); 
    TextView countText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAddCartCount);

     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          String quantity2 = quantity.getText().toString();

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
          if (! quantity2.equals(".") || quantity2.equals("") ||quantity2.equals("-")) {
            count++;
            long newId = myDb.insertRow("GTX 950", 140, quantity2);
            myDb.getRow(newId);
            countText.setText("Successfully added " + count + " Times");
          }
          else
          {
            text2.setText("Quantity needed!");
          }
       }
    });
   }
```

Comment: What's the reason? Does it use less resources? I did it this way because I find modular code easier to read. Having a ton of variables on my onCreate isn't as pleasing to look at.

Comment: @DeanNewb it not a matter of resources. i suggested onCreate becoz it is better to initialize your UI controls before your activity is visble.I mean thats what **onCreate** is meant for and as for moudular approach you can write your code which you wrote in **onClick()** in another function say setupAddRecordButton() and then call that function in **onClick()**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
quantity .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            quantity2=charSequence.toString();
                if (! quantity2.equals(".") || quantity2.equals("") || quantity2.equals("-")) {
        count++;
        long newId = myDb.insertRow("GTX 950", 140, quantity2);
        myDb.getRow(newId);
        countText.setText("Successfully added " + count + " Times");
    }
    else
    {
        text2.setText("Quantity needed!");
    }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```